# Is it good to update Swing client information using web service call every second?

Tags: java, web-services, swing, client, updates

I have a Java Swing application running on client machines and a java server that provides web services with information. I need to update the information that is shown in the swing client application rather often for example every second. Is it a best practice to do that by calling a web service every second and update the information or it will be better if I use some other method?

Answer (score 0):

I think that depends on purpose. Is there any possibility to call the update via user interactions, such as a button click etc.? Because updating with a more or less random time ("1 Second") seems quite dirty to me.

The smoothest way is to implement the Observer Pattern (push). The server notifies the client(s) whether anything has changed or not. For further Information, check wikipedia or [this link](http://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/observer).